# How to give password to protect xlsx sheet using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, passwords, apache-poi

`sheet1.protectSheet("xxxx");`

Actually I tried the above code, it is protecting the sheet from editing, but while I enable editing it does not ask for password, how to protect with password?

Answer (score 0):

Read the Apache POI - Encryption support paragraph XML-based formats - Encryption. It comes with a source code example. See http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html